# Moving a method into SwingWorker

Tags: java, swing, file-io, jtable, swingworker

I am working on a program that analyzes DNA. The main work of the program is in a method that takes in a certain file type, parses the file and converts it into a string, then parses the string to separate it into segments. It then returns the results of the analysis in a `JTable` on a new `JFrame`.

```
public  JTable readFile(File file) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String line;
    String result = "";
    while((line=in.readLine())!=null) {
       if(!line.startsWith(">")) {
              result = result + line;
               }            
    }       

    Sequence sequence = new Sequence("Unspecified", result);
    ArrayList<Contig> contigs = sequence.getReadingFrames();

    String [] columnNames = {"Position", "Frame", "Sequence"};

     Object[][] data = new Object[contigs.size()][3];
     int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= contigs.size() && j < 3; i++){
        if (i == contigs.size()){
            j++;
            i = -1;
        }
        else if (j == 0){
            data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getStartPosition());   
        }
        else if (j == 1){
            data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getReadingFrame());
        }
        else if (j == 2){
            data[i][j] = contigs.get(i).getSequence();
        }
    }
    JTable seqTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
    in.close();
    return seqTable;
}
```

How should I go about moving this into a `SwingWorker`? I tried a copy, paste, and edit, but the whole thing just returns empty results.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help! I used My-Name-Is' methodology as it integrated more easily into my current code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. The source isn't tested due to missing dependencies. You just need to find a way to update your `JTable`. I suggest to create the `CustomSwingWorker` with an instance of your `TableModel` and then just update it within the method: `protected void done()`

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

import javax.sound.midi.Sequence;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableModel;

public class CustomSwingWorker extends SwingWorker<TableModel, Void> {

    private File file;
    private JTable table;

    public CustomSwingWorker(final JTable table, final File file) {
        this.table = table;
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    protected TableModel doInBackground() throws Exception {
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        String result = "";
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            if (!line.startsWith(">")) {
                result = result + line;
            }
        }

        Sequence sequence = new Sequence("Unspecified", result);
        ArrayList<Contig> contigs = sequence.getReadingFrames();

        String [] columnNames = {"Position", "Frame", "Sequence"};

        Object[][] data = new Object[contigs.size()][3];
        int j = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= contigs.size() && j < 3; i++) {
            if (i == contigs.size()) {
                j++;
                i = -1;
            } else if (j == 0) {
                data[i][j] = Integer
                        .toString(contigs.get(i).getStartPosition());
            } else if (j == 1) {
                data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getReadingFrame());
            } else if (j == 2) {
                data[i][j] = contigs.get(i).getSequence();
            }
        }

        in.close();
        return new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
    }

    protected void done() {
        try {
            this.table.setModel(this.get());
        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            // Simply ignore it ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: don't to create an Swing Object inside Background Thread, on exception get() returns a reference to errors description, nothing to the JTable

Comment: @mKorbel `Swing Object` ? DataObject is self made class, or do you mean sth. different?

Comment: `JTable seqTable = new JTable(...` inside Workers Thread, all Swing Object would be initialized, setted, e.i., "ready to use" before ...

Answer (score 2):

I actually have a very similar answer as "My-Name-Is," although I simplified it a lot to try to show the flow of the execution, and not get lost in the details.

Basically, if "the whole thing just returns empty results" I think perhaps you may have messed up the hand-off from the background thread to the GUI thread.  Check your `done()` method carefully to make certain you call `get()` appropriately.

Remember also that Swing is not thread safe and all GUI components (ie, your `JTable`) must be constructed on the EDT, which in this case means inside the `done()` method, and not the background thread.

```
class TableBuilder extends SwingWorker<Object[][], Void> {
   private final String [] columnNames = {"Position", "Frame", "Sequence"};

   @Override
   public Object[][] doInBackground() throws Exception {
      // read your file, and build your data object...
      Object[][] data = new Object[someSize()][3];
      // then return it to the EDT ...
      return data;
   }
   @Override
   public void done() {
      // now on the EDT, build your GUI components, and 
      // update the GUI as needed.
      try {
         Object[][] data = get();
         JTable seqTable = new JTable(data, columnNames);
         // add your seqTable to the gui here...
      } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
         // exit
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: don't to create an Swing Object inside Background Thread, on exception get() returns a reference to errors description, nothing to the JTable

Answer (score 2):

You have at least three options, you could...

### Use `publish`/`process` to populate a pre-existing `TableModel`...

```
public class TableBuilder extends SwingWorker<Object[][], Object[]> {

    private DefaultTableModel tableModel;

    public TableBuilder(DefaultTableModel tableModel) {
        this.tableModel = tableModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[][] doInBackground() throws Exception {
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            String result = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.startsWith(">")) {
                    result = result + line;
                }
            }

            Sequence sequence = new Sequence("Unspecified", result);
            ArrayList<Contig> contigs = sequence.getReadingFrames();

            Object[][] data = new Object[contigs.size()][3];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= contigs.size() && j < 3; i++) {
                if (i == contigs.size()) {
                    j++;
                    i = -1;
                } else if (j == 0) {
                    data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getStartPosition());
                } else if (j == 1) {
                    data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getReadingFrame());
                } else if (j == 2) {
                    data[i][j] = contigs.get(i).getSequence();
                }
                publish(data[i]);
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Object[]> chunks) {
        for (Object[] row : chunks) {
            tableModel.addRow(row);
        }
    }

}
```

### Build the `TableModel` in the `doInBackground` method...

```
public class TableBuilder extends SwingWorker<TableModel, Void> {

    private JTable table;

    public TableBuilder(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    protected TableModel doInBackground() throws Exception {
        DefaultTableModel tableModel;
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            String result = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.startsWith(">")) {
                    result = result + line;
                }
            }

            Sequence sequence = new Sequence("Unspecified", result);
            ArrayList<Contig> contigs = sequence.getReadingFrames();

            String[] columnNames = {"Position", "Frame", "Sequence"};

            Object[][] data = new Object[contigs.size()][3];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= contigs.size() && j < 3; i++) {
                if (i == contigs.size()) {
                    j++;
                    i = -1;
                } else if (j == 0) {
                    data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getStartPosition());
                } else if (j == 1) {
                    data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getReadingFrame());
                } else if (j == 2) {
                    data[i][j] = contigs.get(i).getSequence();
                }
            }
            tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        }
        return tableModel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            TableModel model = get();
            if (model != null) {
                table.setModel(model);
            } else {
                // Handle possible null case...
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

### Return the data needed to construct the `TableModel`

```
public class TableBuilder extends SwingWorker<Object[][], Void> {

    private JTable table;

    public TableBuilder(JTable table) {
        this.table = table;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object[][] doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Object[][] data = null;
        try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
            String line;
            String result = "";
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (!line.startsWith(">")) {
                    result = result + line;
                }
            }

            Sequence sequence = new Sequence("Unspecified", result);
            ArrayList<Contig> contigs = sequence.getReadingFrames();

            data = new Object[contigs.size()][3];
            int j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= contigs.size() && j < 3; i++) {
                if (i == contigs.size()) {
                    j++;
                    i = -1;
                } else if (j == 0) {
                    data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getStartPosition());
                } else if (j == 1) {
                    data[i][j] = Integer.toString(contigs.get(i).getReadingFrame());
                } else if (j == 2) {
                    data[i][j] = contigs.get(i).getSequence();
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            Object[][] rows = get();
            if (rows != null) {
                String[] columnNames = {"Position", "Frame", "Sequence"};
                TableModel tableModel = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
                table.setModel(model);
            } else {
                // Handle possible null case...
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: +1 for 1st code example, still disagree with to get anything from get()

Comment: @mKorbel I could return `Void` for the first example, but I think I was going to demonstrate using `get` to get the `Object[][]` row data as well, but went a different direction...it's all contextual, hence the point for three examples ;) - It also demonstrates possible error handling

Comment: It also demonstrates possible error handling, to creating Swing Object inside Workers Thread, I'm sure that isn't, hmmm :-) crocodile_free :-)